# Filling in an 8x8 minesweeper grid with mines (pt. 1: Rectangle)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

Can you detect where the mines are in this 8x8 Minesweeper grid containing single, double, triple, and anti-mines?

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |  |  | 4 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | -1 |  |  | 21 |  |
|  | 5 | 3 |  | 1 |  | 9 |  |
|  | 3 | -1 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | 3 |  | -5 | -4 | -3 |
|  | 13 |  |  |  | 4 | 5 |  |
|  | 20 |  | 12 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | 5 | 5 |  |

Notes:

1. Anti-mines are worth (-1) mines: there are 17 of them
2. Single mines are worth (1) mine: there are 3 of them
3. Double mines are worth (2) mines: there are 5 of them
4. Triple mines are worth (3) mines: there are 16 of them
5. Partial answers ***are by any and all means definitely allowed***, however, you must figure out the location of all 42 mines to get the green checkmark.
6. I will post a hint in 72 hours if no one has managed to get a total of 21 mines filled out (half the grid).
7. I have checked, and there should only be one unique solution.

Comment: Is a solution required, or can I just post a hidden final grid?

Comment: But $17+2+7+17=43\neq 44$ and $22$ numbered spaces in $8\times 8=64$ grid should give at most $42$ mines.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I'll do a quick recount.

Comment: Also the 1 on the top middle cannot be solved with the 21 next to it; 6 -2 is still 4 not 1

Comment: @Stevo It should be fixed now, I must've rushed through the top a bit. Sorry about that.

Comment: Still infeasible.  The top four clues in column 2 cannot be satisfied simultaneously.

Comment: @RobPratt Oh, and looking at my answer sheet, you're right. The 1 should be a 3. I will most definitely fix that, and sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Still infeasible.  The first three notes cannot be satisfied simultaneously.

Comment: Okay *hopefully this time* the puzzle is fixed. Had to count what each number was and recounted the total number of mines, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Mines now add up, but there are 42 spaces free, so unless there is a random cell left empty, surely there should be 42 mines not 41?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Look I'm sorry I cannot count today, I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Not trying to nitpick. But now the mines add up to 41 still not 42. I actually like this idea and had made good progress (https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVHqW.png) but I can say with certainty there are at least 2 solutions, and the numbers dont add up, so downvoting for now. Should always try to solve a puzzle yourself before posting to check the solution and solution path is unique, I will ofc upvote instead if the problems get fixed, but this is flawed rn

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Holy crap, I did not realize that there were two solutions! Probably because there's a 2x2 box of numbers that's not automatically conjoined by another number in the following row, but I will keep that in mind!

Comment: Still infeasible.

Comment: Cool puzzle! At one point I coded a game that included double and triple mines. It was fun to play. I haven't thought of an anti mine.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky I got the inspiration for anti-mines from [here](https://heptaveegesimal.com/2018/advent-calendar/) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not necessarily unique, one solution of the puzzle is:

> [image]

As far as I can tell, the other solutions

> Switch the (-1,2) in rows 3-4, column 1 or switch the (2,3) in rows 6-7, column 1

I approached and solved this problem by

> Realizing 21 must consist of 7 3s. The additional neighbors of 9 must be -1s (since the sum is already 12). By similar logic, I worked out which pairs of mines were needed for the remaining numbers until it all filled in!

Comment: @CrSb0001 I'm not sure how to hide comments so I added a brief explanation on how I solved it in the body of my post!

Comment: This solution does not satisfy the required counts in notes 1 through 4.  If you ignore those, there are 276 solutions.

Comment: Ahh I didn’t notice that while solving @RobPratt. Do you have the combination of 1/2/3/-1 mines for all the solutions? I’d be interested to see how much they varied if at all

Comment: Here are the ranges of counts for the different values in [-1,3]: $$-1: [15,17], 0: [0,4], 1: [1,6], 2: [2,10], 3: [14,18]$$